# How would you write a test case in python for a function that prints a lot of print statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

i was recently trying to learn how to write my unittest cases. I was able to do for the
basic integer add, sub functions. But now i wanted to do for something more like Passwordchecker. Here is my code.

```
from ast import main
```

from unicodedata import name

```
def PasswordCheck(password):
    
    #To get the length of the passsword
    n = len(password) #score is password > 8 = 10

    #variables to check conditions and rules to score
    startDigit = 0 #score = 10
    hasDigit = 0 #score = 25
    hasChar = 0 #score = 25
    hasUpper = False #score = 15
    hasLower = False #score = 15 
    normalChar = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890" 
    score = 0 
    count = 0
    
    #Iterating through each character
    for i in range(n):
        
        #checks if character is a digit.
        if password[i].isdigit():
            hasDigit += 1
        #checks if character is a speacialcharacter
        elif password[i] not in normalChar:
            hasChar += 1
        #checks if character is Uppercase
        elif password[i].isupper():
            hasUpper = True
        #checks if character is lowercase
        elif password[i].islower():
            hasLower = True
        else:
            continue
    #checks if the first character is a digit
    if password[0].isdigit():
            startDigit = 1

    #Scoring based on the rules
    if startDigit == 0:
        score += 10
    if hasLower:
        score += 15
    if hasUpper:
        score += 15
    if hasChar >= 2:
        score += 25
    if hasDigit >= 2:
        score += 25
    if n >= 8:
        score += 10

    #Printing the Grades for their respective scores.
    if score < 50:
        print('LOW')
    elif score >= 50 and score < 75:
        print('AVERAGE')
    elif score >= 75 and score < 90:
        print('GOOD')
    else:
        print('VERY GOOD')

    #Printing the rules that contribute to the least to the scoring
    if score < 75:
        print("The rules that contribute least towards your password strength\n")
        
        if startDigit == 0 and count < 2:
            print("Your password doesn't start with a Number")
            count += 1
        if n >= 8 and count < 2:
            print("Your password has atleast 8 characters") 
            count += 1
        if hasLower and count < 2:
            print("Your password has lowercase characters")
            count += 1
        if hasUpper and count < 2:
            print("Your password has uppercase characters")
            count += 1
        if hasChar >= 2 and count < 2:
            print("Your password contains more than 2 special characters")
            count += 1
        if hasDigit >= 2 and count < 2:
            print("Your password contains more than 2 numbers")
            count += 1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    password = input("Enter the Password:")
    PasswordCheck(password)
```

my test case is:

```
  import unittest 
from passwordchecker import PasswordCheck

class Testpasswordchecker(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_passwordcheck(self):
        password = "Iampassword1"
        result = PasswordCheck(password)
        self.assertEqual(result, "AVERAGE")


if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

this particular test returns fail! I request anyone to help me learn more about designing these test cases as i am new to python.

Comment: You question is way too broad and the code is very long. Try editing it.

Comment: But something for you to think about is, what does the function actually return? How many return statements are there?

Comment: You have to understand the difference between `return` and `print`. And then you will understand that *"returns a lot of print statements"* makes no sense.

Comment: You could modify the checker to *return* the result and add a trivial "wrapper" with one print statement that prints it. On the first look it may seem like a workaround, but it is more useful to return a value, because such function can act like a building block and be called from other fucntions, not only from a unit test. In general there is a not very exact rule that functions tthat are easy to test tend to be better designed. If some sense it says that you should try to write easy-to-test functions from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) as a function decorator to temporarily replace the built-in `print` function with a `Mock` object within the scope of the test method, so that after calling `PasswordCheck`, you can validate that `PasswordCheck` called `print` with the expected arguments by calling [`Mock.assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls):

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

class Testpasswordchecker(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.print')
    def test_passwordcheck(self, mock_print):
        password = "Iampass"
        PasswordCheck(password)
        mock_print.assert_has_calls([
            call('LOW'),
            call('The rules that contribute least towards your password strength\n'),
            call("Your password doesn't start with a Number"),
            call('Your password has lowercase characters')
        ])
```